# Why does clicking on a tab that changes state and has nothing to do with ajax call creates that ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, jsx

I have a simple layout.

There is a `<StateSelector>` in `<Navbar>` clicking on that executes a method.

The value of innerHTML of that button in `<StateSelector>` is passed as an argument to a function that was passed to it as a prop. And the method present in parent changes the `activeOption` State to `All, Offline and online` depending on the button clicked.

Now, There is one more child to this parent called `<TwitchList>`. This `<TwitchList>`'s render method contains an array of 8 users names and 8 calls are made to `twitch.tv` to get data for those channels.

Note that I have not linked `<StateSelector>` just yet. It has no interaction to `$.ajax();` in `<TwitchList>` except the fact that `<TwitchList>` and `<StateSelector>` belong to same parent.

Why does clicking on a element inside `<StateSelector>` generating ajax calls? 
And clicking on it one time generates 8 calls which is equal to number of users in usersList[].

I have tried searching for this issue and I have tried to work my way around for about 4 days now and I just don't understand why it is happenning.

```
var Navbar = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="navbar">
            <h1 className="header">TWITCH STREAMERS</h1>
            <StateSelector changeActiveOption={this.props.changeActiveOption}/>
        </div>
    );
}
});

var StateSelector = React.createClass({
changeOption: function (e) {
    this.props.changeActiveOption(e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase());
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="selectorList">
            <div  className="selector" onClick={this.changeOption}>ALL</div>
            <div className="selector" onClick={this.changeOption}>ONLINE</div>
            <div className="selector" onClick={this.changeOption}>OFFLINE</div>
        </div>
    );
}
});
var TwitchList = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    var userslist = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
    var finalList = [];
    function makeURL(user, type) {
        return "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/" + type + "/" + user;
    }
    userslist.forEach(function (user) {
        $.ajax({
            url: makeURL(user, "streams"),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                function getID(data) {
                    if (data.stream) {
                        return data.stream._id;
                    } else {
                        return Math.random();
                    }
                }
                function getImage(data) {
                    if (!data.stream) {
                        return "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/ecf0e7/5c5457.jpg&text=0x3F";
                    }
                    else {
                        return data.stream.preview.medium;
                    }
                }
                console.log(data);
                var id = getID(data);
                var preview = getImage(data);
                console.log(preview);
                finalList.push(
                    <li className="twitchUser" key={id}>
                        <img src={preview} alt="preview"/>
                    </li>
                )
            },
            fail: function (xhr, error, url) {
                console.error(error + "          " + xhr + "        " + url);
            }
        });
    });
    return (
        <div className= "twitchListWraper" >
            <ul className="twitchList">
                {finalList}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
});
var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        activeOption: "all"
    };
},
changeActiveOption: function (option) {
    this.setState({
        activeOption: option
    });
},
render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="app-root">
            <Navbar changeActiveOption={this.changeActiveOption}/>
            <TwitchList activeOption={this.state.activeOption}/>
        </div>
    );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/sulihogegi/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time state changes on `<App>`, it re-renders. This includes re-rendering its children (on of which is `<TwitchList>`). Your ajax call is made in `<TwitchList>`'s `render` function, so every time state changes, it's going to be hitting that ajax code.

If you're wondering why the state's changing, it's because you have a function, `changeActiveOption`, that updates the `<App>`'s state being passed to `<Navbar>` which is then passes down to `<StateSelector>`.

The appropriate thing to do here is find a life cycle event in which to make the ajax call. I'd recommend `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUpdate`.

Take a look at [lifecycle functions here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html).

Comment: What is the more appropriate position for it then? If I move it to App and than pass the retrieved data as a prop it will still be called because App is  re-rendered.

Comment: I understand why the state is changing because I am going to use it to create a filterable list based on the option selected. All, offline and online.

I am confused about where should I put ```$.ajax()``` and get the functionality I want.

Comment: This worked. ComponentDidMount proably wasn't working because it is called  after initial Rendering completes. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't write your ajax call to render function of `TwitchList` component instead you can write it to `componentDidMount` function

Comment: I have to important data from the data retrieved from ajax call and then create a ```<li> </li>``` push it into an array and display that array inside a ```<ul>```. I tried this at first but then I can not follow this logic. Because finalList inside componentDidMount will not be accessible in ```render```.

Comment: have you tried to keep  `finalList` in the state so that when it updates you can access the state from the render method?

Comment: Yes, I Did just as MicronXD suggested. This problem is fixed.

But now, I created a state named finalList and pushed the entire array after all 8 ajax calls finish by doing 
``` 
if(finalList.length === 8)   {
      this.setState({
             finalList: finalList
      });
}
```
But it doesn't updates State. 

I'll find my way.


Thank you so much for your answer.